# Increase height of reflected object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Want to reflect an image, and my code looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       height="500" width="500"
                       creationComplete="init(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import flash.filters.BlurFilter;

            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            private var picture:BitmapData;

            private var reflection:BitmapData;
            private var reflectionHolder:Bitmap;

            protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
                loader.load(new URLRequest("assets/rectangle.png"));
            }

            private function onComplete (event:Event):void
            {
                trace("loaded!");
                var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
                picture = new BitmapData(loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height, false, 0xFFFFFF);
                picture.draw(loaderInfo.loader);
                img.source=picture;
                trace(picture.height,picture.width);
            }


            private function createReflection():void 
            {
                reflection=new BitmapData(picture.width,picture.height,true,0x00ffffff);

                var flipMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
                flipMatrix.rotate(Math.PI);
                flipMatrix.scale( -1, 1 );
                flipMatrix.translate(0, picture.height);

                reflection.draw(picture, flipMatrix);

                for (var i:int = 0; i < picture.height; i++) 
                {
                    var rowFactor:Number = Math.max(0, 1 - (i / picture.height));
                    for (var j:int = 0; j < picture.width; j++) 
                    {
                        var pixelColor:uint = reflection.getPixel32(j,i);
                        var pixelAlpha:uint = pixelColor>>24&0xff;
                        var pixelRGB:uint = pixelColor&0xffffff;
                        var resultAlpha:uint = pixelAlpha*rowFactor;
                        reflection.setPixel32(j, i, resultAlpha << 24 | pixelRGB);
                    }
                }

                reflection.applyFilter(reflection, reflection.rect, new Point(0, 0), new BlurFilter(4, 4, 3));

                reflectionHolder=new Bitmap(reflection);
                reflectionHolder.y=img.y+img.height;
                reflectionHolder.x=img.x;
                reflectionHolder.width = img.width;
                reflectionHolder.height = img.height;

                var uIComponent:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                uIComponent.addChild(reflectionHolder);
                this.addElement(uIComponent);
            }

            protected function btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                createReflection();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
        <s:Group height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="0x0d0d0d" height="100%" width="100%"/>
            <s:Image id="img" height="100" width="200" />
            <s:Button id="btn" click="btn_clickHandler(event)" />
        </s:Group>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

it shows result but the out put was not perfect...

[image]

Objective:- Reflected object should be same as the real Object and Have Some Distance From Real Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be very much code to show in one answer. Actually, I searched my very old archives, and I found my old class for reflection (2009 year). It will create reflection for you, It supports animated objects, and also distance from object to start of reflection. With only 2 lines of code:

```
var test:Sprite = new Sprite();
test.graphics.beginFill(0x990099);
test.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
addChild(test);

test.x = test.y = 50;

//Reflection
//test - object that will be reflected
//40 - alpha, 40%
//200 - ratio, max value 0xFF or 255, with 0xFF you will see full object in reflection
//-1 - update frame rate, for animated objects
//0 - some dropoff... actually I don't remember it, don't use it by passing zero, It affects reflection bounds
//10 - distance to the reflection in pixels...
var vars:ReflectVars = new ReflectVars(test, 40, 200, -1, 0, 10);
var reflect:Reflect = new Reflect(vars);
```

And a result:

[image: Reflection]

if you are interested in the class, I could move it to GitHub.

Comment: give me the GitHub Link @nicolas

Comment: I checked sources, I can't move it to the GitHub, I will rewrite (Timers, blend mode masks, etc) library in near future, for now you [could use old source](https://mega.co.nz/#!HEMDGazY!ODw0ZNFlrc9CFSEs4qOuZL4YDklwCpR31wIXg3TOfuk) maybe it helps you. Good luck.

Comment: hi @Nicolas Siver , i have one swf file looks like rectangle. and i used SWFLoader for that , i need to reflect that one so is that Reflect class will work on that or should i covert swf to bitMap data.

Comment: thank you for sharing this let me use this code if i face any problem i will ask you..

Comment: on btn1_CLickHandler if i add those two lines i found this error......Error: addChild() is not available in this class. Instead, use addElement() or modify the skin, if you have one.....at Reflect.as:45(line_no).

Comment: Class was designed for pure AS3 projects. AddElement It's a Flex.

Comment: ok thank you very much i will found some solution for that your code was very usefull... There are some other classes like Reflection manager and Reflector but codes in there are messy but your class was quite understandable i can do any modification if i want...Have a good day.

Comment: i have five conditions like x-axis,y-axis,x=1,x=y and x=-y....this works for x-axis..what should i pass for other 4 conditions..@Nicolas Siver

Comment: You should improve it, because it was designed only for `ordinary` reflections.

Answer (score 1):

```
flipMatrix.translate(0, picture.height);
```

try changing this to

```
flipMatrix.translate(0, picture.height + 20);
```

OR

```
 reflectionHolder.y=img.y+img.height;
```

try changing this to

```
   reflectionHolder.y=img.y+img.height + 20;
```

for adding space between reflection & real picture